# How to refer to another dependency property in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a `UserControl` with two `DataTemplate` dependency properties: `Template1` and `Template2`. I want to render the template in `Template2` via a `ContentControl` in `Template1`. How do I bind to this? I tried using the following, but got binding exceptions:

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Template2}" />
```

Full code:

```
<MyUserControl>
    <MyUserControl.Template1>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="This is in Template1!" />
                <ContentControl ContentTemplate="???" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </MyUserControl.Template1>
    <MyUserControl.Template2>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="This is in Template2!" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </MyUserControl.Template2>
</MyUserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template2">
        <TextBlock Text="This is in Template2!" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template1">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="This is in Template1!" />
            <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Template2}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<MyUserControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Template1}">

</MyUserControl>
```